# Create mock server to test on result of RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, junit, resttemplate, spring-test

I am not sure if it is possible to write a Test case that can mock the "http://localhost:8888/setup" site, so the above code can hit it and I want to check if the    "http://localhost:8888/setup" received the inputStream correctly.

```
InputStream inputStream = //got the inputStream;

SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);

restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

InputStreamResource inputStreamResource = new InputStreamResource(inputStream){
    @Override
    public String getFilename(){
        return filename;
    }
    
    @Override
    public long contentLength(){
        return -1;
    }
}

MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>():
body.add("file", inputStreamResource);

HttpHeader headers = new HttpHeader();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)LinkedMultiValueMap

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

String url = "http://localhost:8888/setup";

restTemplate.postForObject(url, requestEntity, String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try using Wiremock!**

Many ways of using it, back then when I used it, I used to run a JAR (wiremock jar) and it spawns up a program on your localhost with your port specified. Henceforth, you can test by hitting that localhost on the port it's up!

***For reference check this out :***

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/wiremock-tutorial/

https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-wiremock

https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock

Comment: is it possible to use Wiremock  to, kind of mock the "http://localhost:8888/setup" site? I will passing the http://localhost:8888/setup with the MultipartFile, is it possible to use the wiremock and mock the "http://localhost:8888/setup" then download the MultipartFile? I am not so sure if can be done this way

Comment: Wiremock itself is an application which will mimic (or mock) a real service kind of behaviour. It will run on your localhost:(Your_Specified_port) . Depending on which article you refer , I can't assure you regarding downloading multipart file but I believe it should support !